# react-router-dom | path="*" doesn't work on vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, vercel

I'm currently working on developing an application using React along with React Router Dom, and I'm in the process of deploying it on Vercel. So far, all of my routes are functioning as expected, except for the 404 error route. I'm encountering an issue, and I'm seeking assistance to resolve it.

In my React application, I've set up various routes using React Router Dom, and they seem to be working fine. However, the specific route designed to handle 404 errors is not behaving as intended. I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance in troubleshooting and resolving this issue.

App.jxs code:

```
import './App.css'

import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate} from "react-router-dom"
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth"

// Hooks
import {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import { useAuthentication } from './hooks/useAutentication.jsx'

// Pages
import Home from "./pages/Home/Home.jsx"
import About from "./pages/About/About.jsx"
import CreatePost from './pages/CreatePost/CreatePost.jsx'
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard/Dashboard.jsx'
import Login from "./pages/Login/Login.jsx"
import Register from "./pages/Register/Register.jsx"
import Search from './pages/Search/Search.jsx'
import Post from './pages/Post/Post.jsx'
import EditPost from './pages/EditPost/EditPost.jsx'
import NotFound from './pages/NotFound/NotFound.jsx'

// Components
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar.jsx"
import Footer from "./components/Footer.jsx"


//Context
import { AuthProvider } from "./context/AuthContext.jsx"

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(undefined)
  const {auth} = useAuthentication()

  const loadingUser = user === undefined

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setUser(user)
    })
  }, [auth])

  if(loadingUser){
    return <p>Carregando...</p>
  }

  return (
    <div className='w-full'>
      
      <AuthProvider value={{ user }}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <NavBar />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={!user ? <Login /> : <Navigate to="/" />} />
            <Route path="/register" element={!user ? <Register /> : <Navigate to="/" />} />
            <Route path='/posts/create' element={user ? <CreatePost /> : <Navigate to="/login" />} />
            <Route path='/dashboard' element={user ? <Dashboard /> : <Navigate to="/login" />} />
            <Route path='/search' element={<Search />} />
            <Route path='/posts/:id' element={<Post />} />
            <Route path='/posts/edit/:id' element={user ? <EditPost /> : <Navigate to="/login" />} />
            <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
          </Routes>
          <Footer />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </AuthProvider>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

NotFound.jsx:

```
import { useQuery } from '../../hooks/useQuery.jsx'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const NotFound = () => {
    const query = useQuery()
    

    return (
        
        <div className='flex flex-col justify-center'>
            <div className='w-full mx-auto bg-slate-900 h-42 md:h-40 md:mb-20'>
                <h2 className='my-10 flex flex-col mx-auto text-xl w-80vw uppercase font-bold text-slate-300
                md:text-center'>Resultados apartir da busca por: <span className='lowercase text-center mt-5'>{query}</span></h2>
            </div>
            
            <div>
              <div className='flex flex-col justify-center mx-auto w-80vw my-10'>
                  <p className='text-center text-2xl font-bold uppercase mb-10'>Não foram encontrados posts a partir da sua busca</p>
                  <Link className="w-30vw mx-auto my-2 bg-red-600 py-2 rounded-md hover:text-red-900 transition-all duration-500 text-slate-200 text-center
                  md:w-20" to='/'>
                      Voltar
                  </Link>
              </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default NotFound
```

i have to modify my App.jsx code, or something on vercel website?

Comment: please provide your `NotFound` component

Comment: i cant see the problem on the NotFound.jsx. But, done!

Comment: did you solve this problem? please post your solution in the answers so that people facing the same problem can find a solution

Comment: no, I didn't solve it, I said I couldn't see a problem in NotFound.jsx

Comment: i think the problem is on vercel site, but i dont know how i find and solve that

Comment: What exactly is the issue or problem? I don't see any issue in the router/routing code, so maybe the issue is something else. What is the "404/error route"? Please [edit] to clarify in better detail what the specific issue is, including reproduction steps. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Its just put this code on the your root application:

vercel.json:

```
{
    "rewrites": [
        {"source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/"}
    ]
}
```